# How to return the object with just a selected few embedded objects?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

My structure is as follows:

```
{
    day: x,
    events:
    [
        {
            year: y,
            info: z
        }
    ]
}
```

Up to now I created the following query, which I does not return an error but does show anything either (which is wrong).

```
db.days.aggregate([
{ 
    $match: 
    {
        $and:
        [ 
            {
                'day': 'March_13' 
            },
            {
                'events.year': '1870'
            },
            {
                'events.info': {$regex: "./French./"}
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    $unwind: {path: "$events"},
},
{ 
    $match: 
    {
        'info': { $regex: '.*French.*'}
    }
}])
```

From what I read I need to group by _id, but I do not know how to recreate the array with the objects that satisfied the second $match.

Could you please have a look and maybe tell me why the initial query does not work and advise me on a group block?

Some sample data is here:

```
{ 
    "day" : "March_13", 
    "events" : 
         [
             { 
                 "year" : "1929", 
                 "info" : "Peter Breck, American actor (d. 2012)" 
             }, 
             { 
                 "year" : "1929", 
                 "info" : "Joseph Mascolo, American actor" 
             }, 
             { 
                 "year" : "1929", 
                 "info" : "Zbigniew Messner, Polish economist and politician, 9th Prime Minister of the Republic of Poland (d. 2014)" 
             }, 
             { 
                 "year" : "1929", 
                 "info" : "Bunny Yeager, American model and photographer (d. 2014)" 
             }
         ] 
}
```

And here is if I would succeed in querying by the word "American":

```
{ 
    "day" : "March_13", 
    "events" : 
         [
             { 
                 "year" : "1929", 
                 "info" : "Peter Breck, American actor (d. 2012)" 
             }, 
             { 
                 "year" : "1929", 
                 "info" : "Joseph Mascolo, American actor" 
             }, 
             { 
                 "year" : "1929", 
                 "info" : "Bunny Yeager, American model and photographer (d. 2014)" 
             }
         ] 
}
```

Basically I want to check if the field info contains the searched word, and if it does I keep it in the array.

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include some sample documents and your expected result to show what you want achieved with the aggregation framewrok?

Comment: @chridam Please check the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to try running the following aggregation pipeline for the above example to get the desired result:

```
db.days.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "day" : "March_13",
            "events.year": "1929",
            "events.info": /American/
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$events" },
    {
        "$match": {
            "day" : "March_13",
            "events.year": "1929",
            "events.info": /American/
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "day": { "$first": "$day" },
            "events": { "$push": "$events" }
        }
    }

])
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5706b38dcc578484faab815f"),
            "day" : "March_13",
            "events" : [ 
                {
                    "year" : "1929",
                    "info" : "Peter Breck, American actor (d. 2012)"
                }, 
                {
                    "year" : "1929",
                    "info" : "Joseph Mascolo, American actor"
                }, 
                {
                    "year" : "1929",
                    "info" : "Bunny Yeager, American model and photographer (d. 2014)"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: It is wierd but the query does not return anything, but it does not return an error either.

Comment: @PetruDanielTudosiu Did you check how you are applying the regex pattern in the match pipeline?

Comment: @chirdam The regex is .*American.* to match anything that contains American. On the first try it was wrong but after I modified it still didn't return anything.

Comment: @chirdam
db.days.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "day" : "March_13",
            "events.year": "1929",
            "events.info": '.*American.*'
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$events" },
    {
        "$match": {
            "day" : "March_13",
            "events.year": "1929",
            "events.info": '.*American.*'
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "day": { "$first": "$day" },
            "events": { "$push": "$events" }
        }
    }

])

Comment: @PetruDanielTudosiu You're doing it wrong, look at my example above and try the regex without the quotes i.e. try /American/

Comment: @chirdam I tried you code, it did not return anything :-?

Comment: @chirdam Sorry my bad. Forgot to change the db.

Comment: @PetruDanielTudosiu No worries, glad it worked out well for you.

Answer (score 0):

This would be simple if we could use the [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) with the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator or the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator. That being said you have two options, the first one is to use the aggregation framework (as mention in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36485455/3100115)) and the native aggregation pipeline operators which will be faster as coded in C++ but in the pipeline you need to use the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator and if you are dealing with large array, the size of your documents after de-nomalization may exceed the 16MB in which case the aggregation query will fail. If that happen, you can do this using [`mapReduce`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/)

```js
function map() { 
    var events =  this.events.filter(function(element) { 
        return (/American/i).test(element.info) && element.year === "1929";
        });
    emit(this.day, events);
}

db.collection.mapReduce(
    map, 
    function(key, value) {}, 
    { out: { inline: 1 } },
    { query: { "day": "March_13" } }
)
```

Which returns:

```js
{
    "results" : [
            {
                "_id" : "March_13",
                "value" : [
                    {
                        "year" : "1929",
                        "info" : "Peter Breck, American actor (d. 2012)"
                    },
                    {
                        "year" : "1929",
                        "info" : "Joseph Mascolo, American actor"
                    },
                    {
                        "year" : "1929",
                        "info" : "Bunny Yeager, American model and photographer (d. 2014)"
                    }
                ]
            }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 27,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 1,
        "emit" : 1,
        "reduce" : 0,
        "output" : 1
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```